# Cannot find IIS Service in Windows 7

Tags: iis, service, windows-7

When I go to the windows services window in Windows 7 (Start ==> Administrative Tool ==> Service), I can't find IIS Service listed! Am I missing something? I just want to restart the service. I have IIS Manager and can open it. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 174, accepted):

It's called `World Wide Web Publishing Service`, right down near the bottom of the list.

Comment: That's really the only one?  Seems `iisreset` just doesn't have the punch it used to.  (I've had to reboot the OS in some cases to clean things up in these newer versions without `iisadmin`)  Wait found it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635851.aspx `net stop was` apparently does something useful.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to find out Its service name which is `W3SVC`. I wanted to restart it using ansible.