# Deactivate InternetInformationServices IIS on Windows 10

Tags: windows, iis, service, default

I need on my Windows an IIS, but the service should be stopped by default (i.e. at windows startup).
It is possible to deactivate the Service by default?

> this service runs on a Notebook, an I want to save my ressources

thanks

Comment: Start -> Run -> "Services.msc" . Find IIS, right click -> properties -> change startup type to either manual or disabled.

Comment: thanks, this was also my first idea... but i dont find a Service with IIS or "InternetInformation...".

Comment: https://ufile.io/e6ije <- exportfile from my services (only a txt-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find IIS Service in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012313/cannot-find-iis-service-in-windows-7)